# How to optimize multiple sub-queries from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Table such as **tnx_lc_invoice** and **tnx_lc_payment**. I want to generate report from this two tables.

Table schema like below images

**tnx_lc_payment**

[image]

**tnx_lc_invoice**

[image]

I want to generate output like below images

**output**

[image]

I am trying below query and its generate similar output. but i want to optimize this query or any alternative solution for faster result.

```
SELECT
    a.lc_no,
    a.invoiceValue,
    b.paymentValue,
    (
        a.invoiceValue - b.paymentValue
    ) AS shortPaymentValue
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            lc_no,
            sum(invoice_value) AS invoiceValue
        FROM
            tnx_lc_invoice
        GROUP BY
            lc_no
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        lc_no,
        sum(payment_value) AS paymentValue
    FROM
        tnx_lc_payment
    GROUP BY
        lc_no
) b ON a.lc_no = b.lc_no
```

If any other alternative easy solution please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or MySQL? They are all different RDBMSs

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL is ok

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag(s) appropriate for the database you are really using.  Data is generally stored in a single database.

Comment: And in any database question properly identifying which database backend you are using is key to getting the right answer,especially when it comes to performance tuning where the databases specific solutions are often the fastest. It really matters what database is your backend.

Comment: You have no where clause, how large are these tables going to be? Calculating every sum in a two million record table is going to be slow no matter how you query it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using subqueries create an inner direct between them

```
    SELECT
        a.lc_no,
        sum(a.invoice_value) AS invoiceValue,
        sum(b.payment_value) AS payment_value,
        (sum(a.invoice_value) - sum(b.paymentValue)) AS shortPaymentValue
    FROM       tnx_lc_invoice a
    INNER JOIN tnx_lc_payment b      
    ON a.lc_no = b.lc_no
    GROUP BY
        a.lc_no
```

---

The query was not correct because it multiply the rows if both invoice and payments are duplicated on the same lc_no.

So it is necessary to add at least one group by in an inner query.

```
SELECT
        a.lc_no,
        sum(a.invoice_value) AS invoiceValue,
        sum(b.payment_value) AS payment_value,
        sum(a.invoice_value) - sum(b.payment_Value) AS shortPaymentValue
    FROM  (select lc_no, sum(invoice_value) as invoice_value 
           from tnx_lc_invoice group by lc_no) a
    INNER JOIN tnx_lc_payment b      
    ON a.lc_no = b.lc_no
    GROUP BY
        a.lc_no
```

Comment: You might want to consider the possibility of a row in one of the tables without a corresponding row in the other.

Comment: @Davide its not working. can you test this query? its showing negetive value.

Comment: Yes but the OP added the inner join outside the subqueries, so the effect is the same.

Comment: Can you post the results? Using the same data exposed in the question

Comment: I try on sql fiddle.

Comment: this one also not working. i like this solution if its working good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103324/discussion-between-faisal-and-davide-lorenzo-marino).